# Simple List item ID Auto-population

Tags: number

I have a list that I want to go up by one number automatically for each new item, the first item would be 1, then 2, and so on. I have seen a lot of solutions out there for solution to auto-number a list but with outputs like LSA-001-00001, but I just need a simple 1,2,3,4...

What is the easiest way to do this, preferably with no custom coding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What were you planning on using the list for? Technically all lists on sharepoint automatically have number IDs when they are created which increment by 1, just you can't see them. However if you export the list to InfoPath or Access you can see the item ID.

Comment: Or add the ID column to list views you can see them too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realized the ID column is right there in the list view, duh. Thanks to both of you for the help!